# the banach space of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, complete-spaces, analytic-functions

Good day, I studyng about analytic functions and I see this link

[How to show set of all bounded, analytic function forms a Banach space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/145157/how-to-show-set-of-all-bounded-analytic-function-forms-a-banach-space).

My question is: Is it valid if the functions are continuous in the adherence of the region?

Comment: Yes, in the same way that $C([0,1])$ is a closed subspace of $L^\infty([0,1])$, the space of analytic functions continuous on the boundary is a closed subspace of the space of analytic functions bounded on the boundary (all with the $\sup$ norm)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for any open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$ the space of bounded continuous functions on the closure of $\Omega$ that are analytic in $\Omega$ form a Banach space (with the supremum norm).  To prove it you note that if a sequence of such functions converges uniformly, the limit is also such a function.